Trying to use my phone/tablet as a Second Screen without using any sort of cable
I recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu 24.04 and now I am trying to extend my monitor and use my mobile as secondary screen without HDMI Cable.
I tried several ways but still no success, can some help me on this ?

Hi Shoalib. Welcome to the community. You might want to add what kind of phone you have (Android, iPhone). Also, what makes you think this is possible? The information you can give us, the better chance we can help you.

The reason behind this thought, is how windows OS has multiple options of application which could help to use mobile screen as extended screen. So i was hoping if same can be done on UBUNTU OS.
